# apache (httpd) load balancing

Tags: php, mysql, apache, apache2

I have reached a state in my research where I understood that a database-driven web app (portal) can be optimised by replication / scaling (even sharding for huge db) and employing a solution like mysql replication or clustering (Percona).

The following question came up in my head as I was thinking...

"Ok, so database can be safely distributed to users. But what happens if my powerful machine 4 x Xeon CPUs + 16GB ram (max avail in this pack i'm getting) cannot survive to http requests?"

How can one tackle the apache / httpd load-balancing ? Are there any solutions for it ?
Maybe it's very simple, but I don't see one right now.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. The answer seems to be in here allready... "load balancing" .. do you mean to ask "how does loadbalancing work" ? That's way to broad a question for here, do you have a specific question maybe?

Comment: i don't know anything about load-balancing with apache. does it really exist like that ? i think i should look it on the net :) thanks  ...i thought there was a more complex solution to it...

Comment: But the bottomline is that your question is "how do I do loadbalancing for my apache webserver" ?

Comment: i found few solutions regarding a load-balancer which forwards intelligently the tasks to other servers....the thing is in my app I save images...will this save to the load-balancers or to the current active server that serves the pages ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no "simple" solutions at this level.

Although if it's only a research, but not a live site reaching this point - there is no point in theoretical musings. Every application has it's own bottleneck that have to be optimized, and there is no way to predict it just off your head.

And HTTP daemon though seldom being a bottleneck. As a matter of fact, an HTTP daemon often being the very load balancer itself, distributing requests between several application backends and serving static files for all of them.

Comment: thanks. question though, if my app saves images on local hdd, where would it save them if I have a load balancer which forwards the requests to other servers on local net ?